# Assembly language (MIPS) difference betweent addi and add

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to understand the difference between using `addi` and `add`, does both do the same thing?

e.g

```
addi  $t0, $0, $a0
add  $t0 , $0, $a0
```

Answer (score 29):

`add` adds the value in two registers

`addi` adds an immediate value (constant) to the register

[This](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html) gives you some example.

Comment: In the provided url: page not found

Comment: Found it here https://web.archive.org/web/20190417103801/http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html

Answer (score 3):

Adding to answer :

Add syntax looks like this :

**Add  rd , rs , rt** // look difference **rs , rt** here

i.e **rd <--- rs + rt**

**bit(31)|operation code| rs | rt | rd |shift amount|function code| bit (0)**

While addi :

**Addi rt , rd , immediate** // look difference of **rt , rd** compare to ADD

i.e **rd <--- rt + immediate**

**bit(31)|operation code|rs|rt|immediate(16 bits)| bit(0)**